# active x combobox naming issue

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am having a little bit of a strange problem with my VBA code and I am wondering if anyone could shed some light on what is going wrong.

On opening my workbook, this piece of code fires

```
Sub build_SupervisorDropdownBox()

Dim locationRange As Range
Set locationRange = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("O3:W3")

Set sList = Sheets("Dashboard").OLEObjects.Add _
            (ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", _
            Link:=False, _
            DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
            Left:=locationRange.Left, _
            Top:=locationRange.Top, _
            Width:=locationRange.Width, _
            Height:=locationRange.Height)
sList.name = "supervisorList"

End Sub
```

This creates my combobox as expected, however it has the default name of comboBox1.  However, if I then delete this comboBox and run the exact same code again, everything gets created and named correctly and I am at a loss as to why this is happening.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction of what I would need to look at.

Thanks :)

edit: I currently have both supervisorList and sList declared as public variables

Comment: How did you declare `sList`?  Did you delclare it as `OLEObject`?

Comment: Works fine for me - first time creates a combo box called `supervisorList`

Comment: @Domenic at the moment I have sList declared as a varient

Answer (score 0):

Try this below:

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=100, Height:=20).Name = "SomeNameToo"
```

or the below

```
 Set curCombo = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlDropDown, Left:=Cells(1, 1).Left, Top:=Cells(2, 1).Top, Width:=100, Height:=20)
 With curCombo
        .ControlFormat.DropDownLines = 2
        .ControlFormat.AddItem "Temp1", 1 ' Adding data
        .ControlFormat.AddItem "Temp2", 2 ' Adding data
        .Name = "newname"
        .OnAction = "newname_Change"
 End With
```

Comment: Gave both a go, and no joy with either, back to the drawing board for me I think